# Using Cayley's Theorem to find an isomorphic subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Find a subgroup of $S_4$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z}$.

Here is what I have so far: We need to find a subgroup of $S_4$ that is isomorphic to $\{0, 1 \} \times \{0, 1 \}$. Now, $\{0, 1 \} \times \{0, 1 \} = \{(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1) \}$. The pairs $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ tell us that the identity map, $e$, is present. The pairs $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ tell us that the transposition map, $\tau$ is present. So a subgroup of $S_4$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z}$ must be $\{e, \tau \}$.

Comment: This seemed too easy and I'm thinking there must be more. Thank you for your help!

Comment: "the" transposition map? How many elements does $\{e,\tau\}$ have? How many does ${\bf Z}/2{\bf Z}\times{\bf Z}/2{\bf Z}$ have?

Comment: Wikipedia article on [Klein four-group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group) (a.k.a. Viergruppe) mentions permuation representation of this group.

Comment: Do you know GAP? If you like, I can give you the codes. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The number $4$ is just large enough to pick two disjoint transpositions. Say
$$
\sigma=(1,2)\qquad\tau=(3,4).
$$
Now check that the subgroup generated by $\sigma$ and $\tau$ does what you want. More generally, you see why $S_{2n}$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Cayley (or have to, by assignment), take the regular representation as follows. (I am really going through the [proof of Cayley's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem#Proof_of_the_theorem).)

Denote the elements $(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)$ by $1, 2, 3, 4$ in order. Now look at the action of each of them by addition on $(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)$.

Clearly $(0,0)$ acts as the identity $e$.

Now consider $(0,1)$. We have
$$(0,0)+ (0,1) =(0,1),\quad (0,1)+ (0,1) =(0,0),\quad (1,0)+ (0,1) =(1,1),\quad (1,1)+ (0,1) =(1,0),$$
so this is the permutation $(12)(34)$, as $(0,0) \leftrightarrow (0,1)$ and $(1,0) \leftrightarrow (1,1)$.

Now consider $(1,0)$. We have
$$(0,0)+ (1,0) =(1,0),\quad (0,1)+ (1,0) =(1,1),\quad (1,0)+ (1,0) =(0,0),\quad (1,1)+ (1,0) =(0,1),$$
so this is the permutation $(13)(24)$, as $(0,0) \leftrightarrow (1,0)$ and $(0,1) \leftrightarrow (1,1)$.

Now consider $(1,1)$. We have
$$(0,0)+ (1,1) =(1,1),\quad (0,1)+ (1,1) =(1,0),\quad (1,0)+ (1,1) =(0,1),\quad (1,1)+ (1,1) =(0,0),$$
so this is the permutation $(14)(23)$, as $(0,0) \leftrightarrow (1,1)$ and $(0,1) \leftrightarrow (1,0)$.

So the subgroup you obtain is $$\{ e, (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}.$$ Note that it is a [regular subgroup of $S_4$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_group_action#Regular), as always when taking the [regular representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_representation#Significance_of_the_regular_representation_of_a_group).

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try another apporach.

In $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, all elements are of order $2$. In $S_4$, there are only $9$ elements are of order $2$. It is not hard to try some of the elements and get a subgroup that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$.

One example could be $\{e, (12), (34), (12)(34)\}$ and there are a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

For any given bijection $f\colon\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2\to\{1,2,3,4\}$, Cayley's embedding is the composite map $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2\hookrightarrow S_4$ defined by:
$$([i],[j])\mapsto(k\mapsto f(([i],[j])+f^{-1}(k))\tag1$$
In particular, irrespective of the (arbitrary) choice of $f$, the recipe $(1)$ yields: $$([0],[0])\mapsto()$$
But to get the images in $S_4$ of the nontrivial elements of $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$, you've really got to make a choice for $f$, for example:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&([0],[0])\mapsto 4 \\
&([0],[1])\mapsto 3 \\
&([1],[0])\mapsto 2 \\
&([1],[1])\mapsto 1 \\
\tag2
\end{alignat}
*Accordingly*, $(1)$ yields:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&([0],[1])\mapsto(1\mapsto 2) \\
&([0],[1])\mapsto(2\mapsto 1) \\
&([0],[1])\mapsto(3\mapsto 4) \\
&([0],[1])\mapsto(4\mapsto 3) \\
\end{alignat}
and hence $([0],[1])\mapsto (12)(34)$. Likewise for the remaining two elements of $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$.

If you play with other choices $(2)$, you'll find that the isomorphic copy of $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$ in $S_4$ may or may not be normal therein.